# i implemented generic method which is declared in an interface but I got an error

Tags: c#, generics

I declared a generic method in a interface called IDatabase. And I implemented the method in a class named MsSql.cs. But error message says that I didn't implement the method. I don't know what's wrong.

My code is as follows.

in the IDatabase, I declared as follows.

```
T BeginTransaction<T>(string connectionString);
```

And in the MsSql.cs, I implemented as follows.

```
public SqlTransaction BeginTransaction(string connectionString) 
{ 
    tran_con = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
    tran_con.Open(); 
    SqlTransaction transaction = tran_con.BeginTransaction(); 
    return transaction; 
}
```

please let me know why the error was occurred.

Comment: Well, your interface expects a generic argument, while your implementation doesn´t provide any `T`. What do you expect `T` to be? Why is your interface-method even generic?

Comment: In Visual Studio you can click the lightbulb at the top of the class by the error  and have it add an empty implementation for you, that way you can see what will make it happy.

Comment: Is the interface declared as `IDatabase<T>`, and does the class implement `IDatabase<SqlTransaction>`? That's the only way this would work.

Comment: I expect the T is SqlTransaction

Comment: Why is your method generic at all?

Comment: I'm planning to make Oracle connection, and ms sql connection and mysql connection, and so on. So, I'd like to make an interface which can be used no mater what kinds of database i use.

Comment: Where is `T` defined in your interface? Is the interface itself generic or just the method?

Comment: just method. I just declare a generic method in a interface. And I'll implement oracle and ms sql classes which returns verious kinds of types which is dependent on the database.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how generic methods work. What your interface expects is a method with the same signature. When you use `<T>` in a method it means that method is generic, not that it can be implemented with any type. To do what you want to do, you could make the interface generic like this for example.

```
interface IDatabase<T> {
    T BeginTransaction(string connectionString);
}

class MsSql: IDatabase<SqlTransaction> {
    public SqlTransaction BeginTransaction(string connectionString) 
    { 
        tran_con = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
        tran_con.Open(); 
        SqlTransaction transaction = tran_con.BeginTransaction(); 
        return transaction; 
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this is what implementing the genric method would look like:

```
public T BeginTransaction<T>(string connectionString) { 
    // Code that generates any type T based on the connectionString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your interface asks for `T`, you have to provide a `T`, not an `SqlTransaction`, which is in no way related to `T` at all.

But even if there **were** a relation between those types you can´t expect the compiler to guess that you want to use `SqlTransaction` for `T`. Imagine the following situation. You have an instance of your interface:

```
IDatabase db = GetDatabaseInstance();
```

`IDatabaseIDatabase` does not know *anything* about the actual underlying type returned by `GetDatabaseInstance`. So even if you *could* implement `BeginTransaction` this way, how should a caller ever infer that type:

```
db.BeginTransaction(...);  // what should this method return?
```

The only way here is to make your interface itself generic. Then you´re able to indicate at **compile-time** what type `T` is.